# Managing data using GridViews and Groupby

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server, gridview

I'm working on a timesheet reporting application using ASP.NET (C#) GridView and Template Fields with a Sql Server backend. I'm basically grabbing an employee's list of tasks for the week, cycling through GridView using RowDataBound and checking if EndTime falls on Sun - Sat then placing those Hours/Minutes in that column label. You can see an example of my GridView header below (sorry about the formatting).

```
Type|Hours|Minutes|StartTime|EndTime|Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Total
```

The problem is my groupby isn't grouping my tasks together because my StartTime/EndTimes will be unique, but I need to pull those back so I can check which day it falls under, then populate that column (as you can see the two rows it returns below). I thought there may be a way to create a 2nd GridView and populate it based on certain values in the 1st Gridview. Has anyone else stumbled across a problem like this?

```
SELECT 
C.Task,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.StartTime, 101) As StartTime,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.EndTime, 101) As EndTime,
SUM(DATEDIFF(n, A.StartTime, A.EndTime)) / 60 AS Hours,
SUM(DATEDIFF(n, A.StartTime, A.EndTime)) % 60 AS Minutes
FROM dbo.Timesheet A, dbo.Employees B,
dbo.TimeSheet_Master C
WHERE A.CreatedBy = B.ContactId
AND A.Task = C.Task
AND (B.ContactId =@ContactId) 
AND (A.StartTime >= @StartTime) 
AND (A.EndTime <= @EndTime) 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.StartTime, 101), CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A.EndTime, 101), C.Task;

Task    StartTime   EndTime         Hours   Minutes
-------------------------------------------------------
Install 05/17/2011  05/17/2011      1        0
Install 05/18/2011  05/18/2011      1        30
```

Comment: The results you've given us don't show any problem with grouping.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: In other words, I want my grouping to group Both install tasks, then just sum the hours and minutes. So yes, the SQL results are correct but I need the Gridview to perform the grouping and SUM(), then place in the Day of the week column. So there will be one column with Install, showing 1 hour for the Tuesday column, then 1 hr 30 mins for the Wednesday column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what your requirements are, but it's almost like you want to combine a pivot table.

I did this quickly so it may not exactly suit your needs but anyways...

I created a temporary table called #timesheet and added some values:

```
CREATE TABLE #timesheet
(
  Task VARCHAR(10),
  employee INT,
  StartDate DATETIME,
  endDate DATETIME
)

 INSERT  INTO #timesheet (Task, employee, StartDate, endDate) VALUES ('Task1',10,'2011-5-10 17:00:00','2011-5-10 20:00:00' ) 
 INSERT  INTO #timesheet (Task, employee, StartDate, endDate) VALUES ('Task1', 10, '2011-5-12 17:00:00', '2011-5-12 20:00:00' ) 
 INSERT  INTO #timesheet (Task, employee, StartDate, endDate) VALUES  ('Task2',10,'2011-5-12 17:00:00','2011-5-12 20:00:00' )         
 INSERT  INTO #timesheet (Task, employee, StartDate, endDate) VALUES  ('Task1', 12, '2011-5-08 17:00:00', '2011-5-08 20:00:00'  )
```

I created a GetWeekDayNameOfDate function taken from [Kodyaz Development Services](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/get-week-day-name-of-date-using-t-sql.aspx) to get the day of the week.

I first created a summary query as shown below:

```
SELECT  #timesheet.Task,
    #timesheet.employee,
    MIN(#timesheet.StartDate) AS [Start Date],
    MAX(#timesheet.endDate) AS [End Date],
    SUM(DATEDIFF(n, #timesheet.StartDate, #timesheet.endDate)) / 60 AS [Hours],
    SUM(DATEDIFF(n, #timesheet.StartDate, #timesheet.endDate)) % 60 AS [Minutes]
FROM    #timesheet
GROUP BY #timesheet.Task,
        #timesheet.employee
```

That would give me my summary for the task and employee.  It will show the start date and the end date of the entire duration and how many hours and minutes.

My results would be:

```
Task       employee    Start Date              End Date                Hours       Minutes
---------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- -----------
Task1      10          2011-05-10 17:00:00.000 2011-05-12 20:00:00.000 6           0
Task2      10          2011-05-12 17:00:00.000 2011-05-12 20:00:00.000 3           0
Task1      12          2011-05-08 17:00:00.000 2011-05-08 20:00:00.000 3           0
```

I next created a details pivot query to sum the number of hours that were spent on each day of the week.

```
 SELECT Task,
    Employee,
    ISNULL([Sunday], 0) AS Sunday,
    ISNULL([Monday], 0) AS Monday,
    ISNULL([Tuesday], 0) AS Tuesday,
    ISNULL([Wednesday], 0) AS Wendesday,
    ISNULL([Thursday], 0) AS Thursday,
    ISNULL([Friday], 0) AS Friday,
    ISNULL([Saturday], 0) AS Saturday
 FROM   ( SELECT    #timesheet.Task,
                #timesheet.employee,
                dbo.GetWeekDayNameOfDate(#timesheet.StartDate) AS [Day],
                SUM(DATEDIFF(n, #timesheet.StartDate, #timesheet.endDate))
                / 60 AS [Hours],
                SUM(DATEDIFF(n, #timesheet.StartDate, #timesheet.endDate))
                % 60 AS [Minutes]
      FROM      #timesheet
      GROUP BY  #timesheet.Task,
                #timesheet.employee,
                dbo.GetWeekDayNameOfDate(#timesheet.StartDate)
    ) p PIVOT ( SUM(Hours) FOR [DAY] IN ( [Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday],
                                          [Wednesday], [Thursday],
                                          [Friday], [Saturday] ) ) AS PivotTable
```

My results would be:

```
Task       Employee    Sunday      Monday      Tuesday     Wendesday   Thursday    Friday      Saturday
---------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Task1      10          0           0           3           0           3           0           0
Task1      12          3           0           0           0           0           0           0
Task2      10          0           0           0           0           3           0           0
```

Aftwards I joined my two queries together to get the entire picture

```
SELECT  summary.Task,
    summary.employee,
    summary.[Start Date],
    summary.[End Date],
    details.Sunday,
    details.Monday,
    details.Tuesday,
    details.Wendesday,
    details.Thursday,
    details.Friday,
    details.Saturday,
    summary.Hours,
    summary.Minutes
 FROM    ( SELECT    #timesheet.Task,
                #timesheet.employee,
                MIN(#timesheet.StartDate) AS [Start Date],
                MAX(#timesheet.endDate) AS [End Date],
                SUM(DATEDIFF(n, #timesheet.StartDate, #timesheet.endDate))
                / 60 AS [Hours],
                SUM(DATEDIFF(n, #timesheet.StartDate, #timesheet.endDate))
                % 60 AS [Minutes]
      FROM      #timesheet
      GROUP BY  #timesheet.Task,
                #timesheet.employee
    ) summary
    INNER JOIN ( SELECT Task,
                        Employee,
                        ISNULL([Sunday], 0) AS Sunday,
                        ISNULL([Monday], 0) AS Monday,
                        ISNULL([Tuesday], 0) AS Tuesday,
                        ISNULL([Wednesday], 0) AS Wendesday,
                        ISNULL([Thursday], 0) AS Thursday,
                        ISNULL([Friday], 0) AS Friday,
                        ISNULL([Saturday], 0) AS Saturday
                 FROM   ( SELECT    #timesheet.Task,
                                    #timesheet.employee,
                                    dbo.GetWeekDayNameOfDate(#timesheet.StartDate) AS [Day],
                                    SUM(DATEDIFF(n, #timesheet.StartDate,
                                                 #timesheet.endDate)) / 60 AS [Hours],
                                    SUM(DATEDIFF(n, #timesheet.StartDate,
                                                 #timesheet.endDate)) % 60 AS [Minutes]
                          FROM      #timesheet
                          GROUP BY  #timesheet.Task,
                                    #timesheet.employee,
                                    dbo.GetWeekDayNameOfDate(#timesheet.StartDate)
                        ) p PIVOT ( SUM(Hours) FOR [DAY] IN ( [Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday] ) ) AS PivotTable
               ) details ON summary.Task = details.Task
                            AND summary.Employee = details.Employee
```

By doing so I would get the following result:

```
Task       employee    Start Date              End Date                Sunday      Monday      Tuesday     Wendesday   Thursday    Friday      Saturday    Hours       Minutes
---------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Task1      10          2011-05-10 17:00:00.000 2011-05-12 20:00:00.000 0           0           3           0           3           0           0           6           0
Task1      12          2011-05-08 17:00:00.000 2011-05-08 20:00:00.000 3           0           0           0           0           0           0           3           0
Task2      10          2011-05-12 17:00:00.000 2011-05-12 20:00:00.000 0           0           0           0           3           0           0           3           0
```

Mind you, I pretty much ignored the minutes portion but I would hope that at least this could be helpful for you.

Comment: This worked flawlessly for me. I ended up dismissing Hours and calculating everything in minutes, then letting .NET handle the toHours conversion. Thank you, I'd vote this up if I could.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to group by week.  Look [here](http://www.sqlhacks.com/Dates/Group-By-Week) for a headstart, and let us know if you need help with the full solution.